# Ubuntu 18.04 Ethernet not managed

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have an issue on Ubuntu 18.04 that Ethernet is not managed. However Internet works fine, but it makes it impossible for me to set up vino screen sharing.

Here are some outputs:

```
superuser@SuperTower:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
eno1    ethernet  unmanaged  --         
vmnet1  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
vmnet8  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --  



superuser@SuperTower:~$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.228  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ba85:84ff:fea3:c235  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:85:84:a3:c2:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1365  bytes 842871 (842.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 792  bytes 98547 (98.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0x93200000-93220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 66  bytes 5663 (5.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 66  bytes 5663 (5.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.69.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.69.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.116.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.116.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no


superuser@SuperTower:~$ ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 feb  2 23:28 /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf


superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=none



superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I have tried solutions from various questions here and also

```
superuser@SuperTower:~$ sudo nmcli dev set eno1 managed yes
```

but nothing helps. Still unmanaged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to do the magic:

```
superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no


superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan


superuser@SuperTower:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=none
```

Also, just restarting network-manager service did not help. Only full reboot.