# removed network-manager from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I accidentally removed the network-manager from my ubuntu 18.04 machine. Now I can't connect to internet. My Wifi and wired connection interface got removed and without internet I cant reinstall them. What would I Do now? Please help!

Here is the output of the command `nmcli device`

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 

wlp3s0  wifi      connected  Room-419   
enp2s0  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --         
ppp0    ppp       unmanaged  --
```

Comment: If you removed just the package, you can download it from a different computer and transfer it via USB. Or you can download it on your phone and use bluetooth. In either case, use `sudo dpkg -i *deb` to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect via Ethernet cable to the network with DHCP server (dynamic IP addresses).

Then run DHCP client manually with `sudo dhclient` <kbd>Tab</kbd> (for auto-completion) and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
On my system the complete command is `sudo dhclient enp0s3`

Note: if unsure then  run `ip link` and you will find at least two interfaces here:

> ```
> $ ip link
> 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
> 2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
> ```

and you will find ethernet as `enp0s3` (may vary in your case). Ensure that you can ping some server on the net - for example `ping ubuntu.com`. If you cannot ping - then try with other (third) ethernet interface.

Then install manager to the system:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager # for console
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome # for GNOME and Unity desktops
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Fixed! I was thinking about installing ubuntu again. thanks! I am grateful.

Comment: Great! So you can [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) my answer :)

Comment: yeah obviously! but I have some issues till now. such as I can not go to the settings on my ubuntu. I did everything as you said but there is no wired connecion available. I can not use the inter by plugging in the ethernet cable which is connected to my router

Comment: Which desktop environment did you use before uninstalling network manager?

Comment: I used Gnome. I still use it.

Comment: Then try to add new ethernet connection from `nm-connection-editor`. Specify *Device* on the *Ethernet* tab and click *Save*.

Comment: nothing changes even I added an ethernet connection. I

Comment: Then please add output of `nmcli device` to the question.

Comment: I do not know the history of your system. The final solution may vary if you previously have netplan of ifupdown enabled or something similar. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1115132/66509 as a possible solution.